# How to RDP using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rdp

I would like to run a python script from a local machine (win10 pc) to connect to one or multiple windows server 2016 machines, and get information such as disk space, CPU and memory usage, etc. Have been reading forums and but didn't quite get the right moodule to use. Does anyone have a similar program written or if anyone can help me with the base code using the right module to RDP to a windows server, I would really be grateful.

TIA!

Comment: Did you google `rdp python` ? This may be useful: https://pypi.org/project/rdpy/

Comment: You can try with RDP but I would check WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation) first. You can see in this example this is easy to use: https://coreygoldberg.blogspot.com/2008/12/python-monitor-windows-remotely-with.html

Comment: @Oded BD This is great. Thank you. I will try it out.

Comment: @coder_3476 let me know if it works for you, so I will post it as answer as well